# Grid with 2 column, vertical align items in second columns if odd number of items

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, css-grid

I need to create 2 columns layout which will align items in the second column vertically if the number of items is odd. Can't realize how to do it. A number of items are unknown.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.item {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```

[image: Example of what I mean]

Here is a link to Codepen if someone prefers this editor.
https://codepen.io/anatoly314/pen/bGvRmEa

Thank you!

Comment: So No 7 should be in the second column?

Comment: No, @Paulie_D, he meant that whatever elements are in the second column, they all should be vertically aligned

Comment: No, items 2,4 and 6 should be vertically aligned relatively to whole second column.

Comment: Nope still don't get it, vertically aligned to what? How are they not aligned now? What is this supposed to look like?

Comment: If you mean *stretch* the second column to be the same size as column one, then you can't do that.

Comment: @Paulie_D added picture of what I mean

Comment: Yeah, not possible, that's not a grid

Comment: @Paulie_D is there any option to do it other way?

Comment: Not with your current structure, you need two **actual** column containers. Even then I'm doubtful since nth-child would not work.

Comment: added a second snippet to my answer. You won't get better without hacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hacky solution to use with caution:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin: 5px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
}

/* 
 translate all the elements in the second column 
 when we have odd elements 
*/
.item:first-child:nth-last-child(odd) ~ .item:nth-child(even) {
  transform:translateY(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

Also like below if you want to fill all the space:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin: 5px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
}


.item:first-child:nth-last-child(odd) ~ .item:nth-child(even) {
  transform:translateY(50%);
}
/* no transform for the fist item in the second column */
.item:first-child:nth-last-child(odd) + .item:nth-child(even) {
  transform: none;
}
/* make first and last item in second column bigger */
.item:first-child:nth-last-child(odd) + .item:nth-child(even),
.item:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(even){
  height: 150%;
}
/* smaller transform for the last item since it's bigger */
.item:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(even) {
  transform:translateY(33%)!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
</div>
```